# C# WebApiConfig MapHttpRoutes with Action AND optional DateTime(-string) AND optional id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, constraints

I have a C# Web API with a few HttpGET and HttpPOST-methods in my API-Controllers. Here below a list of all of them to know what I want to achieve:

ProductsController:

```
// GET: {host}/api/products/all/{device_id}/{date}
[ActionName("all")]
public IEnumerable<ProductsAPI> GetAllProducts(string device_id, string date);

// GET: {host}/api/products/one/{device_id}/{date}/{id}
[ActionName("one")]
public ProductsAPI GetProduct(string device_id, string date, int id);

// POST: {host}/api/products/save/{device_id}
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveProductChanges([FromBody] Data data, [FromUri] string device_id);
```

CategoriesController:

```
// GetAllCategories & GetCategory similar to ProductsController
// (included date string)
```

OrdersController:

```
// GetAllOrders & GetOrder & SaveOrderChanges similar to ProductsController
// (included date string)
```

TagsController:

```
// {host}/api/tags/all/{device_id}
[ActionName("all")]
public IEnumerable<TagsAPI> GetAllTags(string device_id);

// {host}/api/tags/one/{device_id}/{id}
[ActionName("one")]
public TagsAPI GetTag(string device_id, int id);
```

UsersController:

```
// GetAllUsers & GetUser similar to TagsController
// (excluding the need for a date string)
```

TestController:

```
// GET {host}/api/test/enable/{device_id}
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("enable")]
public String enableTests(string device_id);

// GET {host}/api/test/disable/{device_id}
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("disable")]
public String disableTests(string device_id);
```

Before this change I didn't included the Date-string in the Products, Categories and Orders and everything worked perfect when I used the following WebApiConfig's MapHttpRoute:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now my question is: How should I define my MapHttpRoute now that I've added the Date to some (not all) of my API-Controllers?

I did try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByDate",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{date}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { date = @"d{2}-d{2}-d{4}" /* dd-MM-yyyy */, id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
```

But now none of my HttpGets are working anymore.. ('Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.') Both with date (`{host}/api/products/all/{device_id}/07-08-2014`) and without date (`{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}`)..

Does anyone know what is wrong with my MapHttpRoutes and how I should change it?

---

EDIT 1:

I've changed the date constraints to `date = @"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$" /* dd-MM-yyyy */` like [@Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199949/c-sharp-webapiconfig-maphttproutes-with-action-and-optional-datetime-string-an/25200536#25200536). I've also tried his other suggestion of removing the `constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }` from the top MapHttpRoute. When I do this my requests like `{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}` are working again, but the ones with the date like `{host}/api/orders/all/{device_id}/07-08-2014` are giving me the following error:

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
'http://localhost:*my_port*/api/orders/all/*given_device_id*/07-08-2014'.",
"MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Orders' that matches the request."}
```

---

EDIT 2:

I've also tried a single MapHttpRoute like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WebApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{all_id}/{one_id}",
    defaults: new { all_id = RouteParameter.Optional, one_id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { all_id = @"^((\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})|([0-9]+))$", one_id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
```

With the same calls as before, but with the parameter names changed (The ones using date [Products, Categories, Orders] have `date` changed to `all_id` and `id` changed to `one_id`. The ones that aren't using date [Users, Tags] have `id` changed to `all_id`.)

But now none of my HttpGETs are working (once again) anymore (`Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.`). (PS: I know I'm pretty bad at regex and MapHttpRoutes, so does anyone know a complete solution so all my HttpGets and HttpPosts are working, of all API-Controllers?)

---

EDIT 3:

There seems to be something wrong with the constraints.. It almost looks like when constraints are added in the MapHttpRoute, the `RouteParamter.Optional` is ignored.. (I probably did something wrong though, but can't figure out what.) I tried adding a MapHttpRoute before my original MapHttpRoute, this time without constraints like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WebApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{all_id}/{one_id}",
    defaults: new { all_id = RouteParameter.Optional, one_id = RouteParameter.Optional }//,
    //constraints: new { all_id = @"^((\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})|([0-9]+))$", one_id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now almost everything is working:

```
{host}/api/products/all/{device_id}/07-08-2014  // works
{host}/api/products/one/{device_id}/07-08-2014/5  // works
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}  // works
{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5  // doesn't work (gives same result as "users/all/{device_id}")
{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/bla/5  // works (but shouldn't work..)
// Haven't tested the HttpPOSTs yet
```

Still, would prefer it if I could add constraints..

But even with my old code (before date was ever applied), constraints doesn't work when I add them:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
);
```

Without the constraints this works:

```
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}  // works
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}/5  // works
```

With the constraints this doesn't work..:

```
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}  // doesn't work (error: "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found. ")
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}/5  // partly works (gives all users, but shouldn't need "/5" for this..)
{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5  // doesn't work (error: "No action was found on the controller 'Users' that matches the request.")
```

So I'm pretty confused about constraints' impact in the MapHttpRoutes.. :S And I'm still no where near a working solution after all these trial and errors I did..

---

Edit 4:

After another [suggestion of @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199949/c-sharp-webapiconfig-maphttproutes-with-action-and-optional-datetime-string-an?noredirect=1#comment39315804_25199949) I tried to separate All and One:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiAll",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/all/{device_id}/{date}",
    defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { date = @"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiOne",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/one/{device_id}/{id}/{date}",
    defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { date = @"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", id = @"^\d+$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiGet",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiPost",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
);
```

And added `[HttpGet]` to all my GetOne and GetAll methods.

With the following results:

```
{host}/api/products/all/{device_id}/07-08-2014  // works
{host}/api/products/one/{device_id}/5/07-08-2014  // works (NOTE: date and id are switched now, but I don't mind this)
{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}  // works
{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5  // doesn't work ("Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.")
{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5/00-00-0000  // works (but I want it to work without the date as well..)
{host}/api/test/enable/{device_id} // works
// Haven't tested the HttpPOSTs yet
```

So, now almost everything works, except for `{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/{id}` (and also with tags instead of users). It looks like the `defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional },` isn't working in the second (and first) MapHttpRoute.

If I can't find any solution I just stick with this one and just provide `/00-00-0000` when I want a single User/Tag.. >.> I have a deadline and it already took me way, way longer than expected to simply add the date to the URL-Route..

EDIT 4b:

If I remove the `[ActionName("one")]` and `[ActionName("all")]` from my methods, it seems that `{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}` isn't working either (`"No action "all" was found on the controller 'Users' that matches the request."`), so that means when I keep the ActionNames it uses the third MapHttpRoute instead of the first for the GetAllUsers-method.. The `date = RouteParameter.Optional` isn't working at all when I provide a constraint for it..

Comment: In third edit that with two constraints this line '{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5' works as '{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}'. This is actually expected because your first route has id parameter optional that is why it matches it.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Hmm ok. But still, I have `[ActionName("all")]` and `[ActionName("one")]` explicitly above the methods, so I would assume that when I use `{host}/api/users/one/{device_id}/5` it should use the GetUser method with the ActionName "one", instead of the GetAllUsers with ActionName "all", even though the both MapHttpRoute matches the URL-path. Anyway, I'm a bit confused about how all this works and also a bit frustrated. If anyone know a solution to cover all my HttpGETs provided in the comments above my API-Controller's methods I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you need to split your "all" and "one" routes in separate routes.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Ok, I've tried to split them and made an Edit once again (EDIT 4). Only one isn't working yet (and I also haven't tested the HttpPOSTs yet, will do this when all HttpGETs are completely working). PS: I've switched the date and id in the MapHttpRoute for `"one"`.

Comment: Please check edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date constraint is incorrect - you missed backslash before "any digit" specifier `\d`.
Try this constraint:

```
date = @"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"
```

EDIT:
It seems that you are right that constraints break optional parameters. Check [this post](http://james.boelen.ca/programming/webapi-routes-optional-parameters-constraints/) for same issue.

What i ended up doing is adding possibility of empty string to regexs. You can do that by specifying `^$` separated from rest of regex using `|`.

Also I've added `action="actionname"` to defaults and made `date` parameter nullable.

Route config:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiAll",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/all/{device_id}/{date}",
    defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional, action="all"},
    constraints: new { date = @"^$|^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
 );
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiOne",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/one/{device_id}/{id}/{date}",
    defaults: new { date = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "one" },
    constraints: new { date = @"^$|^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$", id = @"^$|^\d+$", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
 );
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiGet",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
 );
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiPost",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
 );
```

Controller action methods (code is based on ootb values controller):

```
 [ActionName("all")]
 [HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<string> Get(string device_id, DateTime? date = null)
 {
      return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
 }

 // GET api/values/5
 [ActionName("one")]
 [HttpGet]
 public string Get(string device_id, int id, DateTime? date = null)
 {
      return "value";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction (+1), but it still doesn't work. Also the one without the Date constraint (so for example `{host}/api/users/{device_id}`) doesn't work anymore now that I have two MapHttpRoutes with constraints instead of a single one without..

Comment: And if you delete constraint from first route (not removing second) then '{host}/api/users/{device_id}' works?

Comment: Wait, but url which you provided '{host}/api/users/{device_id}' does not match your route because you are missing '{action}' parameter.

Comment: Ah I indeed ment `{host}/api/users/all/{device_id}`. Anyway, I've tried your other suggestion of removing the constraints from the top MapHttpRoute. Then the ones without date are working again, but the ones with date are giving me an `No Action found error` (I've made an EDIT to my original post).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Edit, this did the trick! Too bad I can't upvote you once again. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

for the original issue, with a constraint on id and being optional, you have to make the REGEX entry "optional" as well.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{device_id}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"(\d+)?" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Derek Wade, i had the same issue. Your answer solved it.